# Error : invalid asm.js : Invalid member of stdlib when executing node deploy.js

Tags: solidity, truffle-deployment

Unable to deploy contract on Rinkeby network using infura and mnemonic of metamask account.

I am using Atom as IDE for writing smart contract using solidity.

As soon as I execute node deploy.js, I get error as invalid member of stdlib
I tried reinstalling npm, solc, truffle-hdwallet-provider but to no luck.
Even the console.log does not print anything on console.

[image]

Below is the dependency in my package.json:

"dependencies": {
    "ethereumjs-testrpc": "^6.0.3",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.4.3",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "python": "0.0.4",
    "solc": "^0.4.25",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.8",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
  }

deploy.js

```
   const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
   const Web3 = require('web3');
   const {interface,bytecode} = require('./compile');

   const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
     'my mnenonic',
     'infure URL'
   );

   const web3 = new Web3(provider);

   const deploy = async()=>{

   const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

   console.log('Attempting to deploy from account',accounts[0]);

   const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!!'] })
    .send({gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

   console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);

  };
  deploy();
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with dependencies, try removing node_modules and running `npm install`.

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't work. Seems like there is some sort of mismatch between solc, truffle-hdwallet-provider and web3.

Comment: It is hard to recommend somthing to try without a way to reproduce your error. A couple of things: * "ethereumjs-testrpc" is redundant with "ganache-cli" so it is better to remove it, * There are several bugs affecting recent versions of web3 v1.0, probably you want to force an specific version  "web3": "1.0.0-beta.37" (ie remove the `^` in front of the version), if that doesn't work try with "1.0.0-beta.34".

Answer (score 0):

Try install truffle hdwallet like this

> $ npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider

then import hadwallet like this

> const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

Answer (score 0):

It's ganache and/or Jest doing that to me. This issue is related: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2549